# RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 31 but got size 30 for tensor number 2 in the list

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I'm using Pytorch-lightning to train my **Convolutional Post Machine (CPM) model**. CPM model requires 2 input, which is **the actual image** and **a center-map** of the image, and the output would be **a heatmap** of the image, which is actually a set of key-points. I used [freiHAND](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/danieldelro/freihand) dataset to train this model and I got a `Runtime Error` , when I tried to use that trained model on a random image I read for testing.

##### CPM model

```
class CPM(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, k, test_size = 0.2, verbose = False):
        super(CPM, self).__init__()
        self.k = k
        self.test_size = test_size
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss().cuda()
        self.pool_center = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=9, stride=8, padding=1)
        self.conv1_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool1_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv2_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool2_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool3_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv4_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.conv5_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(32, 512, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.conv6_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv7_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(512, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1)

        self.conv1_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool1_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv2_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool2_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool3_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv4_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.Mconv1_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.Mconv1_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.Mconv1_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.Mconv1_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.Mconv1_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

    def _stage1(self, image):

        x = self.pool1_stage1(F.relu(self.conv1_stage1(image)))
        x = self.pool2_stage1(F.relu(self.conv2_stage1(x)))
        x = self.pool3_stage1(F.relu(self.conv3_stage1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_stage1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv6_stage1(x))
        x = self.conv7_stage1(x)

        return x

    def _middle(self, image):

        x = self.pool1_stage2(F.relu(self.conv1_stage2(image)))
        x = self.pool2_stage2(F.relu(self.conv2_stage2(x)))
        x = self.pool3_stage2(F.relu(self.conv3_stage2(x)))

        return x

    def _stage2(self, pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage2(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage2(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage2(x)

        return x

    def _stage3(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage2_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage3(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage2_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage3(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage3(x)

        return x

    def _stage4(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage4(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage3_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage4(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage4(x)

        return x

    def _stage5(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage4_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage5(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage4_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage5(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage5(x)

        return x

    def _stage6(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage5_map, pool_center_map):
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage6(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage5_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage6(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage6(x)

        return x

    def forward(self, image, center_map):


        pool_center_map = self.pool_center(center_map)
        conv7_stage1_map = self._stage1(image)
        pool3_stage2_map = self._middle(image)
        Mconv5_stage2_map = self._stage2(pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage3_map = self._stage3(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage2_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage4_map = self._stage4(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage5_map = self._stage5(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage4_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage6_map = self._stage6(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage5_map,
                                         pool_center_map)

        return conv7_stage1_map, Mconv5_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map, Mconv5_stage4_map, Mconv5_stage5_map, Mconv5_stage6_map
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, _ = self.tr_process_(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, sync_dist=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, heat = self.tr_process_(batch, batch_idx)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, sync_dist=True)
        return loss
    
    def tr_process_(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, heatmaps, centermaps = batch 
        heatmaps = torch.autograd.Variable(heatmaps)
        centermaps = torch.autograd.Variable(centermaps)
        heats = self.forward(imgs, centermaps)
        loss = (self.criterion(heats[0], heatmaps) + self.criterion(heats[1], heatmaps)
                    +self.criterion(heats[2], heatmaps) + self.criterion(heats[3], heatmaps)
                     +self.criterion(heats[4], heatmaps) + self.criterion(heats[5], heatmaps))
        return loss, heats[-1]
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1000)
        return [optimizer], [scheduler]
    
    def train_dataloader(self):
        IMG_SIZE = 244 
        HP = HandPose(df, transform = transform, testSize = self.test_size, imgSize = IMG_SIZE, subset = 'train')
        Data = data.DataLoader(HP, shuffle = True, batch_size = 64, num_workers = 2, persistent_workers=True)
        return Data
    
    def train_dataloader(self):
        IMG_SIZE = 244 
        HP = HandPose(df, transform = transform, testSize = self.test_size, imgSize = IMG_SIZE, subset = 'validation')
        Data = data.DataLoader(HP, shuffle = True, batch_size = 64, num_workers = 2, persistent_workers=True)
        return Data
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        IMG_SIZE = 244 
        HP = HandPose(df, transform = transform, testSize = self.test_size, imgSize = IMG_SIZE, subset = 'validation')
        Data = data.DataLoader(HP, shuffle = False, batch_size = 64, num_workers = 2, persistent_workers=True)
        return Data
```

##### Training

```
kpts       = 21 
precision  = 32 
epochs     = 20
IMG_SIZE = 244
sample_run = True if epochs < 2 else False
trainer    = Trainer(fast_dev_run = sample_run, log_every_n_steps = 1, accelerator='gpu',
                    precision = precision, max_epochs = epochs, auto_lr_find = True, 
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
model      = CPM(k = 21, verbose = True, test_size = 0.05)
print(f'DEV run : {sample_run}')
trainer.fit(model)
```

##### Error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_24/1125616526.py in <module>
----> 1 kpts = predict(model, img)

/tmp/ipykernel_24/86724376.py in predict(model, img)
     11 
     12     model.eval()
---> 13     heats = model(img, centermap)
     14     return get_kpts(heats[-1], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
     15 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/tmp/ipykernel_24/2682757597.py in forward(self, image, center_map)
    148         pool3_stage2_map = self._middle(image)
    149         Mconv5_stage2_map = self._stage2(pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map,
--> 150                                          pool_center_map)
    151         Mconv5_stage3_map = self._stage3(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage2_map,
    152                                          pool_center_map)

/tmp/ipykernel_24/2682757597.py in _stage2(self, pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map)
     84 
     85         x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage2(pool3_stage2_map))
---> 86         x = torch.cat([x, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
     87         x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage2(x))
     88         x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage2(x))

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 31 but got size 30 for tensor number 2 in the list.
```

I tried to read a random image from the from the training dataset, and also used the same pre-processing step I used for training the dataset and yet I got this runtime error while testing the model. I'm expecting to make this model work the same it did during training.

##### Testing

```
def predict(model, img):
    IMG_SIZE = 244
    transformer = A.Compose([A.Resize(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)])
    img = transformer(image = img)['image']
    print(img.shape)
    img = torch.from_numpy(img).permute(-1, 0, 1) / 255
    img = torch.unsqueeze(img, dim = 0)                   
    centermap = torch.from_numpy(get_centermap(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 5)).permute(-1, 0, 1)
    centermap = torch.unsqueeze(centermap, dim = 0)
    print(img.shape, centermap.shape)
    
    model.eval()
    heats = model(img, centermap)
    return get_kpts(heats[-1], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)

def get_random_img(fname = TR_IMGS):
    fpath = os.path.join(EV_IMGS, np.random.choice(os.listdir(EV_IMGS)))
    return read_img(fpath)

img = get_random_img()
show_img(img)
kpts = predict(model, img)
```

Comment: Your images are not power of 2, so when you start pooling in a moment you got odd shape. Maybe you can check if the shape is odd, and if it is, just substract 1 to get even shape.